# What kind of Join to see non-existent values in Join table?

Tags: mysql

I have the tables `users`, `locations` and a join table. The join table also has a rank value for each individual at that location, because those individuals have higher ranks at certain locations than at other locations.

```
users
=========
id | name
=========
 1 | john
 2 | bob
 3 | alex

locations
===============
id | name
===============
 1 | san diego
 2 | dallas
 3 | new york
 4 | denver

join_users_locations
==============================
user_id | location_id | rank
==============================
      2 |           1 | 4
      2 |           2 | 3
      2 |           4 | 2
      3 |           1 | 2
      3 |           2 | 4
```

You can see that in the join table a user is only listed if they have a rank at that location. They are not even in the table if their rank is zero/null.

I'm wanting to get query results like this:

```
name |  location | rank 
=======================
 bob | san diego | 4
 bob |    dallas | 3
 bob |  new york | 0
 bob |    denver | 2
```

As you can see, I want all locations to be in the list, even ones that the user isn't joined with (just give those fields a rank value of zero).

It's easy to get the list of locations and ranks for locations he/she is joined with:

```
SELECT
    u.name,
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN join_users_locations jul ON jul.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN locations l ON l.id = jul.location_id
WHERE u.id = 2
```

But that only lists what locations the user is joined with. I want to see the non-joined locations as well.

I know this is possible, but I'm not sure what the solution is. I've tried some different types of JOINs with various results.

[SQL FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a46a/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a [`CROSS JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) from `users` to `locations`.

```
SELECT
    u.name,
    l.name AS location,
    IFNULL(jul.rank, 0) AS rank
FROM
    users u CROSS JOIN
    locations l LEFT JOIN
    join_users_locations jul 
        ON jul.user_id = u.ID 
        AND jul.location_id = l.id
WHERE u.id = 2
```

Comment: Ah interesting... never used a CROSS JOIN before. Got it work perfectly here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a46a/8  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Left *outer* join. Outer joins include everything "on the left" of the join, even if there's no corresponding tuple on the left. You'll probably get null instead of 0, though. Is that ok?
(you can set the null value display to be 0, if not)

Comment: all of the values you inserted have ranks, though. If I change one of the inserts to have a rank of null and rerun it I get exactly what you want. Except a blank instead of a 0. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f52c/2

Comment: I'm not following. Can you copy/paste a SQL Fiddle url?

Comment: btw, a cross join is equivalent to a left and right outer join.

Comment: @Colleen Not to be pedantic, but a `left` and `right outer join` is a `full join`, not a `cross join`... a `cross join` is a [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.name,l.name as location,jul.rank
FROM users u,locations l,join_users_locations jul
WHERE u.id = jul.user_id AND
      jul.location_id = l.id AND
      u.id = 2
UNION
SELECT 'bob' AS NAME,A.NAME AS location,A.RANK_NULL AS RANK
FROM
(SELECT *,IFNULL(RANK,0) AS RANK_NULL
FROM (SELECT * FROM JOIN_USERS_LOCATIONS JUL WHERE JUL.USER_ID=2 )JUL
RIGHT JOIN LOCATIONS L
   ON JUL.LOCATION_ID = L.ID
WHERE RANK IS NULL)A
```

OR

```
 SELECT IFNULL(JUL.NAME,'bob'),L.NAME,IFNULL(RANK,0) AS RANK
FROM  (SELECT U.NAME,JUL.USER_ID,JUL.LOCATION_ID,JUL.RANK 
       FROM USERS U,JOIN_USERS_LOCATIONS JUL 
       WHERE U.ID=JUL.USER_ID AND JUL.USER_ID=2 
      ) JUL
      RIGHT JOIN 
      LOCATIONS L
   ON JUL.LOCATION_ID = L.ID
```

Comment: The implicit joins in the where clause would have the same effect as doing inner joins... jul.rank would never be null, and this can't return any locations for which the user doesn't have a record in `join_user_locations`...

Comment: Made it very complicated for u guys... :)